# See Awarded Bounty Info similar to Vote Counts

Tags: feature-request, bounties, privileges, vote-count

I regularly find myself clicking on votes so I can see the breakdown

[image: Imgur]  [image: Imgur]

Sometimes, I'll mistakenly click on the Bounty Awarded in an attempt to see its breakdown

[image: Imgur]

Obviously, this doesn't work. But could it? It might be interesting to be able to see a breakdown of all bounties awarded and maybe even by whom they were awarded.

Answer (score 3):

You can browse the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11227902/revisions) to see bounties awarded.